# Правильно ли поставлены запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

(1) ***Ему не больно, но досадно и не понятно, как отсюда выбраться***.

Другой вариант: (2) *Ему не больно, но досадно, и не понятно, как отсюда выбраться.*

**Какой вариант правильный и почему?**  (Здесь есть общее дополнение ***ему,***  но есть и предлог НО).

Чем варианты отличаются по смыслу и интонации?

Answer (score 1):

С запятой - один смысл, без запятой - другой.

1. Ему не больно, но досадно, и [ему] не понятно, как отсюда выбраться.
2. Ему не больно, но досадно и не понятно.

Comment: Вариант 1 - это сложное предложение? Но ведь в нем есть общее дополнение "ему", тогда запятая не ставится? Вариант 2. Союз НО по смыслу вроде бы должен связывать только два первых наречия, а это не так, он относится и к третьему тоже.

Comment: В варианте 1 мы обособляем "но досадно". А предложение простое. Вариант 2 формально же все равно возможен?

Comment: Я не думаю, что в первом варианте есть обособление. Второй же вариант формально правилен, но он выражает неточную семантику.

Comment: Ну как же нет обособления... *Ему не больно и не понятно.* А теперь: *Ему не больно, но досадно, и не понятно...*

Comment: Я думаю, что союз НО  - это сочинительный союз, служащий в простом предложении для связи однородных членов, он не используется   в качестве пояснительного или присоединительного союза, стоящего в начале обособленного члена.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта правильные. Уступка, обозначенная союзом *но*, может включать "не понятно", а может и нет. В этом  разница по смыслу. А по интонации — есть пауза или нет.

Примечание. Вопрос о слитном/раздельном написании *не* здесь не рассматривается.

Comment: Текст учебный, и трудно требовать от него идеальной сочетаемости формы и смысла, но хотя бы на отдельные моменты стоит обращать внимание. Что мне здесь не нравится? Плохо, когда оба варианта правильны. По смыслу только наречие 1 и наречие 2 связаны противительной связью (союз НО), поэтому надо бы поставить запятую. А как тогда объяснить грамматику, это уже не однородные сказуемые, а сложное предложение? Но как быть с общим местоимением "ему"? Оно может связывать основы в сложном предложении, и тогда запятая не ставится?

Comment: По-моему, если стоит запятая, то считаем, что второе [ему] пропущено. Более того, возникает оттенок присоединительности. В конце-концов, даже у Розенталя встречается мысль, что запятая иногда ставится, чтобы прояснить смысл фразы.

Comment: Мы можем разделить предложение на две части, соответствующие двум ситуациям и считать его сложным (правда, это уже вопрос вузовской, а не школьной грамматики). По семантике так и надо сделать, обозначив паузу запятой, но вот общее дополнение как-то не вписывается в эту картину. Есть же общее правило у того же Розенталя, например:У Евсеича сорвалась какая-то большая рыба и вдобавок щука оторвала удочку (Акс.);  Здесь даже у второго предложения есть собственное наречие, а вот запятой нет. Я же могу подписать: щука (у него) оторвала удочку.  Так что правила надо соблюдать, особенно в школе.

Comment: Просто не нужно предлагать школьникам решать задачи высшей математики. Для них ответ один — запятую не ставить.

Comment: А у меня тоже одна рекомендация к уважаемым педагогам: не надо сочинять тексты на заданное правило и портить детям художественный вкус.И если уж они за это берутся, то не надо допускать очевидных ошибок, объяснение которых напоминает решение задач по  высшей математике.